# How can you determine if a certain html table header exists using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

Let's say I have the following table:

```
<table id="mytable">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Col 1</th>
    <th>Col 2</th>
    <th>Col 4</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
</tbody>
```

and I want to see if it has a certain column based on if there is a "th" with that text?  Is there a way to have a "HasColumn" method like this below?

```
  var hasCol = HasColumn("#mytable", "Col 1");
  //hasCol = true;

  var hasCol = HasColumn("#mytable", "Col 50");
  //hasCol = false;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the `:contains` selector but it doesn't use the *exact* match criterion, i.e. if you pass `Col 1` to the selector and one of the elements has `Col 12` text content then it will select that element as it *contains* the specified text. I'd use the `filter` method:

```
var hasColumn = $('#mytable thead th').filter(function() {
   return this.textContent === 'Col 1';
}).length > 0;
```

Here is a vanilla JavaScript alternative:

```
function hasColumn(tblSel, content) {
    var ths = document.querySelectorAll(tblSel + ' th');
    return Array.prototype.some.call(ths, function(el) {
         return el.textContent === content;
    });
};

var hasCol = hasColumn('#mytable', 'Col 1');
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [**:contains()**](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)

```js
    console.log($('#mytable th:contains(Col 1)').length);
    console.log($('#mytable th:contains(Col 50)').length);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="mytable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Col 1</th>
      <th>Col 2</th>
      <th>Col 4</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function HasColumn(selector,text){
    return $(selector +' th:contains('+text+')').length > 0;
}
```